# [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Unable to get property 'Id' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, vue.js, computed-properties

tested it with chrome, firefox, opera and internet explorer
and the error only occurs in firefox.

I have two computed properties in vue js and they change pretty much at the same time.
when i change my select box both get triggered because `this.gekozenWinding` get changed when i select a different option inside the select box.

Here is my code for both properties:

```
kant() {
  if (this.gekozenWinding != null) {
    var id = this.haalID(this.windings, this.gekozenWinding);
    parseInt(id);
    if (id < 5 && id > 0) return true;
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
},
graden() {
  if (this.gekozenWinding != null) {
    var id = this.haalID(this.windings, this.gekozenWinding);
    switch (id) {
      case "1":
        return "180"; break;
      case "2":
        return "0"; break;
      case "3":
        return "270"; break;
      case "4":
        return "90"; break;
      case "5":
        return "180"; break;
      case "6":
        return "0"; break;
      case "7":
        return "270"; break;
      case "8":
        return "90"; break;
    }
  } else {
    return "0";
  }
}
```

My method haalID()

```
    haalID(lijst, item) {
  /*
  1.Filters out given item(string) from a lijst(array).
  2.Gets the ID from the filtered object.
  3. returns the ID
  */
  var id = lijst.filter(i => i.Descriptions[0].Description == item);
  id = id[0].Id;
  return id;
}
```

And this is inside my template

```
          <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-9">
          <label>Winding</label>
          <select
            class="form-control"
            v-model="gekozenWinding"
          >
            <option
              v-for="winding in windings"
              v-bind:key="winding.Id"
            >{{winding.Descriptions[0].Description}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div v-if="gekozenWinding != null && gekozenWinding != 'To determine'">
        <div class="parent1" v-if="kant ">
          <img id="fto1" src="../assets/buitenkant.png" alt>
          <img
            id="fto2"
            v-bind:style="{'transform': `rotate(${graden}deg)`}"
            src="../assets/A.png"
            alt
          >
        </div>
        <div class="parent2" v-else>
          <img id="fto3" src="../assets/Binnenkant.png" alt>
          <img
            id="fto4"
            v-bind:style="{'transform': `rotate(${graden}deg)`}"
            src="../assets/A.png"
            alt
          >
        </div>
      </div>
```

Again this only occurs in internet explorer(using the 11) other browsers works perfectly.
I even tried to change my code mutliple times can't get it to work in IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrow functions are not supported in IE11 (or any IE for that matter).

[caniuse.com/#search=arrow%20functions](https://caniuse.com/#search=arrow%20functions) -

You'll need to use a compiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/), or avoid arrow functions.

```
var id = lijst.filter(function (i) {
  return i.Descriptions[0].Description == item;
});
```

Comment: still getting the same error only in IE. Even tried to place the method code (haalID) directly inside my properties.

Comment: Found the problem, it wouldn't filter if the string is a sentence, so i removed the white space from item(string) and Description(property)

Answer (score 0):

Probably this error is in template. (Do your `windings` have `Id`)?

Change `key` to `$index` in option's `v-for`

```
<option v-for="(winding, $index) in windings"
    v-bind:key="$index">
{{winding.Descriptions[0].Description}}</option>
```

PS: Not sure why you are not seeing this error in other browsers..

Comment: Found the problem, it wouldn't filter if the string is a sentence, so i removed the white space from item(string) and Description(property).